# Annotate column value based on another column value on chart using matplotlib python

Tags: python, matplotlib

I have three columns in pandas frame Date, close, and Signal. In signal, I will have either one or zero. When I have one in the Signal column, I require to mark/point to a close value of the same row on the chart. How can archive using plot annotate and or plot text etc? I tried but not work. I appreciate your help. Thanks.

Below is similar but in excel, and I require matplotlib with python.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

You can try something like this:

```
x, y, s = [df[col] for col in df.columns]

fig, ax = plt.subplots()
ax.plot(x,y)
ax.scatter(x[s==1], y[s==1], c='g')
for i,j,k in zip(x,y,s):
    if k==1:
        ax.annotate('High', xy=(i,j), xytext=(i,j + 5))
```

You can have have a look in the annotate [documentation](https://matplotlib.org/stable/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.pyplot.annotate.html) to change offset or where to place your text.

Comment: Thanks. it's the perfect solution for me!!